# How to find if a file exists having prefix PY

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a shell script in which I am trying to find if any file starting with "PY" prefix exists. If it exists then I need to preform certain actions.
My code is

```
#!/bin/bash
export FILE=/usr/local/a/PY_`date +%Y%m%d`*.txt
if [ -e $FILE ] 
then
// do something
else
//do something else
fi
```

What is wrong with this? It is not identifying the file and the control is always going in else block even when file is present there. Please help!

Comment: you are looking for a file name that matches the current date every time. Is this really what you want?

Comment: yes... for example today the file generated will eb having name PY_2018100912345.txt. I would like to search file with name PY_20181009*.txt

Comment: Why don't you use a loop?

Comment: What if there is more than one filename?  You will end-up with `$FILE` having more than one filename and the test `[` will fail.  Do you get any error messages?

Comment: @cdarke there is logic to remove the file as soon as the script ends. so that scenario is handled

Comment: In that case your code works for me, except that it fails on the `//` (might be a comment in some languages, but not this one).  You should quote in `-e "$FILE"` for safety, by the way.

Comment: @cdarke // i have used here in stackoverflow just for clarity. not using in script. "$FILE" not working for me. It actually consider * to be part of filename and not special character

Comment: Is the user executing script has permission for the file. Try `echo $FILE; ls -l $FILE;` after `export FILE=/usr/local/a/PY_`date +%Y%m%d`*.txt` and check.

Comment: `Bash` will try to expand the `*` but if it finds none that match then the `*` is used as a literal part of the filename.  From `man bash`:  *If  no  matching filenames are found, ..., the word is left  unchanged.*  Don't put quotes around filename expansion (glob) characters like `*` , it won't expand inside quotes, I was suggesting you use them with the `-e`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about find:

```
find /usr/local/a/ -maxdepth 1 -name "PY_`date +%Y%m%d`*.txt" -exec <do_something> \;
```

(I'm not sure whether to use maxdepth 1 or 0)

Answer (score 1):

There could be another way to achieve this:

Get the count of the number of files of type `PY_`date +%Y%m%d`*.txt`,and if the count is greater than equal to 1, then do your actions:

```
#!/bin/bash

Date=$(date +%Y%m%d)
file_count=$(find /usr/local/a -type f -name "PY_${Date}*.txt"|wc -l)
if [[ "$file_count" -ge "1" ]]
then
//do your actions//
else
//do something else//
fi
```